# Using Server data in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

My client side JQuery is receiving an array of JSON which i intend to access and use like so:

(array being received is called **crude**)

```
script.

            jQuery(function ($) {

                var x = 0;

                alert(!{JSON.stringify(crude[x])});       
            });
```

However if I try to access the individual components of the array it does not seem to fire the JQuery at all.

It does however fire when I use **0** instead of the variable x as follows:

```
script.

            jQuery(function ($) {

                var x = 0;

                alert(!{JSON.stringify(crude[0])});       
            });
```

I am sure that the array passed is not empty.

Comment: What are you getting in console.log(); ?

Comment: thanks for your consideration but i was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by storing a value in the session and then passing it to the rendered page and use it as a counter. The fetched array needs a variable from the back end too and could not accept a value that was locally declared.